# I am having trouble instantiating methods.

Tags: c#, module, instantiation

To illustrate the problem I built a ConsoleApplication.

It seems to me that I should be able to instantiate a method like this:

```
Vehicles.Car car = new Vehicles.Car();
```

But it doesn’t work.  For the life of me I can’t see what is wrong.

```
Program.cs contains this:

namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehicles.Car car = new Vehicles.Car();
        }
    }
}
```

Vehicles.cs contains this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    public class Vehicles
    {
        public void Car()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a car");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include the error.  Error CS0426 The type name 'Car' does not exist in the type 'Vehicles'

Comment: Clarifying what you actually want to achieve could help - there is really no common concept called "instantiating methods". Based on the sample code it could be attempt to use delegates, static method, class constructor, namespaces or something totally different.

Comment: As I am learning, my vocabulary is not up to par.  I appreciate you helping me with my terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Vehicles` like a namespace, and `Car` like a class.

It should be

```
var vehicles = new Vehicles();
vehicles.Car();
```

From the code shown in your question. This however, is missing many facets from the goal I would assume, but in this narrow scope that is the issue here.

Comment: Thank you! I had things really confused!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vehicles v = new Vehicles();
        v.Car();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your expanded answer really helped me to comprehend what you were saying.